# Scripting to alter Bitbucket diff colours

Tags: css, colors, stylish

I have quite a bad red/green colorblindess, and when I'm reviewing pull requests on BitBucket I really struggle to tell apart the red and green on it. Years ago I had a small script a friend wrote on the plugin Stylish to alter the colors (to a blue and a darker red) which was fantastic and really helped. I've lost it however and I'm not really experienced enough with this sort of coding to rewrite it.

Would anyone be able to give me some pointers for doing this?

Thanks

Comment: As the official documentations said, it's not possible to change the highlight color on Bitbucket. But I hope someone can help you with a custom script ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windwos 10 provides Colorblind mode, it may be helpful if you are a Windows user.

**Use Settings To Turn/Off Colorblind Mode**

1. Navigate to the search box and type **“color filter“**.
2. You will see a list of search results, click **Turn color filters on or off** from the top.
3. Now you have to use the toggle button to **“Turn on color filters”** that is available under **Use color filters**.
4. You will see a list of **color filters** and **color blindness filters**, select the one that is suitable for you.

To quickly activate or deactivate the mode there is a keyboard shortcut to Turn On/Off Colorblind mode. You can always use  **Win+Ctrl+C** keys to Turn On/Off your current filter.

Reference: [Windows 10’s secret Colorblind mode](https://mspoweruser.com/if-you-dont-see-all-the-numbers-heres-how-to-switch-on-windows-10s-secret-colorblind-mode/)

Comment: Oh neat! That definitely helps a bit (and I'm leaving it on for other programs too!). The paler bits of the diff are still a bit hard to tell apart, but the rest is much clearer.